# Nice read about reverb

Tags: acoustics

Not a question, but thought this was an interesting article about some reverb/acoustics in England :)

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-20773690

Comment: I was gonna mention that one too ;) that Greenwich foot tunnel is well cool. Watch out for crazy cyclists even though they're not meant to ride in it! Wish they'd sampled the ballon pops from all locations so we could've IR-ed them tho :p

Comment: yes...its a very dumbed down article. But interesting nonetheless 

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as flagged, it really isn't a question